# How to return custom status code in nestjs?

Tags: node.js, typescript, api, nestjs, http-status-codes

I have my system that has custom errors like this:

```
import { ExtendableError } from './extandable.error'

export const customError = {
  EMAIL_EXIST: () => new ExtendableError({
    message: 'USER WITH SUCH EMAIL ALREADY EXIST',
    code: 403
  }),

  INVALID_EMAIL: () => new ExtendableError({
    message: 'INVALID EMAIL',
    code: 400
  }),

  INVALID_PASSWORD: () => new ExtendableError({
    message: 'INVALID EMAIL OR PASSWORD',
    code: 403
  }),

  EMAIL_DOES_NOT_EXIST: () => new ExtendableError({
    message: 'EMAIL DOES NOT EXIST',
    code: 404
  }),

  TOKEN_DOES_NOT_EXIST: () => new ExtendableError({
    message: 'TOKEN DOES NOT EXIST',
    code: 404
  }),

  DIFFERENT_PASSWORDS: () => new ExtendableError({
    message: 'PASSWORDS ARE NOT SAME',
    code: 400
  }),

  CURRENT_PASSWORD_ERR0R: () => new ExtendableError({
    message: 'CURRENT PASSWORD IS INCORRECT',
    code: 400
  }),

  SAME_PASSWORDS_ERROR: () => new ExtendableError({
    message: 'CANNOT CHANGE SET NEW PASSWORD AS OLD PASSWORD',
    code: 403
  })
}
```

Here I can write my own error responses
When I request something, and for example emails exists, it throws an error that such email while registration already exists.

It states here:

```
async createAccount (doc: RegisterDto, verificationLink: string) {
      if (!isValidEmail(doc.email)) {
        return customError.INVALID_EMAIL()
      }

      const user = await this.existByEmail(doc.email)

      if (!user) {
        return customError.EMAIL_EXIST()
      }// HERE I RETURNING AN ERROR TO CONTROLLER
      doc.password = await bcrypt.hash(doc.password, SALT_ROUNDS)
      const created = await this.repository.create(this.registerMapper.toDomain(doc))
      await this.emailService.sendVerificationEmail(created, verificationLink)
      return created
    }
```

Here is my function in controller:

```
@Post('/api/register')
    async register(@Body() registerDTO: RegisterDto, @Request() request, @Response() response) {
      const verificationLink = `${request.protocol}://${request.header.host}/api/verify-account/`
      return await this.service.createAccount(registerDTO, verificationLink)
    }
```

In postman, it shows me the body and the response, but the actual result of the status code has `201` code
How can I fix it?
[image: postman response]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `return customError.INVALID_EMAIL()` you should `throw` an error.
From [npm docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extendableerror):

```
let ExtendableError = require('extendable-error');

class MyCustomError extends ExtendableError {};

throw new MyCustomError('A custom error ocurred!');
```

Comment: I've decided to use `new HttpException()`, but u provide me an idea, I'll share my solution later on

Answer (score 5):

try this (ref: https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#library-specific-approach)

```
import { Controller, Get, Res, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Response } from 'express';

@Controller('route01')
export class MyController {
  @Get('testResponse')
  async testFuntion(@Res() response: Response) {
     
     if('some condition') {
        return response.status(HttpStatus.OK).send(data);
     } else {
        return response.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).send(data);
     }
  }
}
```

if you need to custom function to create your own response you can use
service to create too but need to pass response to function too like this

```
import { HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Response } from 'express';

service1(response: Response, data: any) {
  return response.status(HttpStatus.OK).send(data);
}
```

```
@Controller('newcc')
testFuntion(@Res() response: Response) {
  const myCustomResp = this.service1(response, 'some data')
}
```